# Django voting system: Determine rank in appropriate way

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a simple voting system but the problem is while displaying the rank of participants. For example if there are 20 participants and 10 have same votes then all of them are ranked same. All the participants have date_joined. So i want to re rank the participants having same number of votes based on date_joined. Any suggestions?

Below is the model for participants:

```
class participants(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fullname = models.CharField(max_length =50)
email = models.EmailField(max_length =50, default='')
display_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename, max_length=500, help_text="Select display image")
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
dob = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
gender =models.CharField(max_length =10)
competition_name = models.CharField(max_length =50,null=True, blank=True)
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
total_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
unique_key =  models.CharField(max_length =50, blank = True)
```

Below is the view:

```
def view_participant(request, participant_id):
//i want to display the rank of the participant from participant_id. Also the id of next and previous ranked user id. 
// I have tried the following code: 
    participant_data = participants.objects.get(id=participant_id)
    rank = participants.objects.filter(total_votes__gt=participant_data.total_votes).count()
    ranked_data =participants.objects.order_by('-total_votes')
    next_rank=0
    prev_rank=0
   if rank == 0:
        #checks if the participant is there is only one participants
        if rank ==0 and ranked_data.count() == 1:
            next_rank=0
            prev_rank=0
        
        #checks if the participant is first and there is more than one participants
        elif rank ==0 and ranked_data.count() > 1:
            next_rank = (ranked_data[rank+1]).id
        #checks if the participant is last
        elif rank == (ranked_data.count() -1):
            prev_rank = (ranked_data[rank-1]).id

    #checks if the participants rank is in between first and last rank
    elif rank > 0 and rank < (ranked_data.count() -1):
        prev_rank = (ranked_data[rank-1]).id
        next_rank = (ranked_data[rank+1]).id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're wanting?

**views.py**

```
ranklist = Participants.objects.all().order_by('total_votes', 'date')
```

You could also make a separate model for your votes:

**models.py**

```
class vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(participants, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and then annotate a vote count to each user, sort by that, and secondarily sort by date joined.

**views.py**

```
ranklist = Participants.objects.all().annotate(votes=Count('vote')).order_by('-votes', 'date_joined')
```

As far as displaying their rank, you can use {{forloop.counter}} to display their position in the list.